# Dynamic table not displaying on mobile device.. similar static data does?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

I'm running into an issue where a dynamically created table in PHP, echo'd in the body of the HTML tag, is not displaying at all on my mobile device. The same information is displayed correctly on my PC.

If I take the output from PHP in text form and paste it into the HTML portion, then the table displays correctly, in both my mobile and desktop environments.

For example, the following will display correctly in both my mobile and desktop environments.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-sm text-nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Class</th>
      <th scope="col">Heading</th>
      <th scope="col">Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Default</th>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="table-primary">
      <th scope="row">Primary</th>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-secondary">
      <th scope="row">Secondary</th>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As an example, the following will **only** display on my desktop correctly.

```
<?php

$_tble = '    <tr>
      <th scope="row">Default</th>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="table-primary">
      <th scope="row">Primary</th>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-secondary">
      <th scope="row">Secondary</th>
      <td>Cell</td>
      <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>';

?>


<table class="table table-striped table-sm text-nowrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Class</th>
      <th scope="col">Heading</th>
      <th scope="col">Heading</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <?php echo $_tble; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone have any suggestion or ideas as to why this might be happening??

Using - Bootstrap 4.3, php 7.2.33

Comment: Did you test it with Chrome devtools mobile preview?

Comment: I would think something different is the problem .. missing CSS, sessions, wrong path to c:\ not available om mobile... I do not see any issue with the code above

Comment: Like a fool I didn't test it in Chrome only IE... it also doesn't work in Chrome. I'm unfamiliar with the devtools in Chrome, I'll look into that. Looking at the source in Chrome and the page is void of anything between the <body> tags...

Comment: Wait...   The code does not work in Chrome on a Desktop computer? Then you are in trouble :-P    then IE has cached a long bygone version of something.   Hit F12 for devtools and ...  There is a cheap UDEMY course on it.

Comment: This now appears to be a recordset problem..  IE/Firefox has records (array (size=4)) in the recordset  Chrome/IOS (NULL) do not...

Comment: Indeed it was a recordset problem... mainly the $sql contained an upper case reference to one of the tables which works in IE/Firefox but does not in Chrome/IOS. Thank you for your reply's.

Comment: Not sure how to upvote the comments without any arrows next to your comments, be glad to though if you can direct me??? thanks

Comment: I did not know there were no arrows :-O

Comment: should I then arrow the question, there is a "main" arrow there?? or maybe post a comment as a solution?

Comment: Correct way: Post your solution as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This originally appeared to be an issue with the creation of the table in PHP but ultimately turned out to be an issue with the $sql used to build the table.

The $sql was handled differently in different browsers. Inadvertently a TABLE name in the query was coded in upper case which correctly ran in IE/Firefox but not in IOS/Chrome.

For example:

```
Select * FROM TABLE1;
```

should have been written

```
Select * FROM table1;
```